# A better way to express a multitude of dot products?

Tags: python, numpy

is there a better and faster way to express the following dot-products in numpy?
I have the following shapes:

```
>>> h.shape
(600L, 400L, 3L)
>>> c.shape
(400L, 3L)
```

I want to calculate the following, if possible without a loop:

```
ans = np.empty((600, 400))
for i in range(400):
     ans[:, i] = h[:, i, :].dot(c[i, :])
```

I think it should be possible with a simeple reshape, but i don't see how atm.

Comment: You create `ans`, but you assign to `a`.  And I think there is a problem with the shapes in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, the shapes are looking strange but are ok. The c[i, :] will be a 1d array and so the alignment is ok.

Comment: I prefer both of the current answers to this, so I won't make it an answer, but `(h*c).sum(2)` should also work-- it'll be slower and use more memory than either of those.

Comment: DSM: Yeah, that a factor five slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to Warren's solution, which I think is the best, there is the undocumented `inner1d`:

```
>>> from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
>>> a = inner1d(h, c)
>>> np.allclose(a, ans)
True
```

From its docstring:

> **inner1d(x1, x2[, out])**
>
> inner on the last dimension and broadcast on the rest: (i),(i)->()

For this particular case, on my system, `inner1d`is slightly faster than `np.einsum`:

```
In [2]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,jk->ij', h, c)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.85 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit inner1d(h, c)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
```

Comment: umath_test has a lot of useful features. matrix_multipy from there with rollaxixs can also be used.

Comment: Using h1 = rollaxis(h, 1) and matrix_multiply(h1, c[:, :, None]) is a factor three slower.

Comment: @tillsten There is a whole new set of functionality, scheduled for numpy 1.8 I believe, that adds generalized ufuncs with most linear algebra operations, and other convenience operations, e.g. adding three arrays without intermediate storage. You can browse the source code, mostly for the docstrings, [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/numpy/blob/83556f62189d25315c65f585834861e0693a3fd6/numpy/core/src/umath/gufuncs_linalg.py), although it doesn't seem to be as final as I thought.

Comment: @Jaime I'm not sure if all the pieces are already there, but a [huge pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3220) that adds linalg gufuncs was merged a few days ago.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `numpy.einsum`

```
ans = einsum('ijk,jk->ij', h, c)
```